# Getting name of subclass from superclass?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a base class `bc` and a number of subclasses based on `bc`.

```
class bc(Object):
  def get_subclass_name(self):
      # Retrieve the name of the most derived subclass of this instance
      pass
  def somemethod(self):
      x = self.get_subclass_name()

class sc1(bc):
    pass

class sc2(bc)
    pass
```

The idea is that when `somemethod()` is invoked on an instance of a subclass of `bc`, it will be able to use the name of the most derived subclass of that instance without needing to know in advance what potential subclasses may exist.

I have put together a test case for this:

```
class base_class(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_subclass_name(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    def somemethod(self):
        print(base_class.get_subclass_name())

class sub_class(base_class):
    pass

sub_class().somemethod()
```

When this code is run it produces `base_class` rather than `sub_class`.

Comment: What does it mean `the most derived subclass` ?

Comment: @falsetru If you have a class bc and a subclass sc1 derived from bc and another subclass sc2 derived from sc1, then the subclass sc2 will be the most derived class of bc for any instance of sc2..

Comment: What if there is another `class sc3(sc2)`, is the "most derived subclass" for an instance of `sc2` then `sc3`, or still `sc2`?

Comment: May be you should try metaclasses for this?

Comment: @livsky I looked at metaclasses but could not see how they would help in this particular case.

Comment: @tobias_k I am talking about retrieving the name of the actual class of an instance from a method in a superclass of the class instance.

Comment: @Jonathan That's what class methods do...

Comment: Please provide a test case of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `print(base_class.get_subclass_name())` note this line! Call it with `self`, than it works. You are explicitly passing the base class, not the current class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just as an alternative to @poorsod's solution, which works perfectly fine for me, here's another, perhaps simpler variant without class methods, using `self.__class__`. Just as `self` always points to the current instance, `self.__class__` always points to the *actual class* of that instance.

```
class bc(object):
    def get_subclass_name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__
```

Example, tested in Python 2.6.6:

```
>>> class sc1(bc): pass
>>> class sc2(sc1): pass
>>> class sc3(sc2): pass
>>> print sc2().get_subclass_name()
sc2
```

If this does not work, please be more specific as to what output you expect and what output you are getting instead.

Comment: I was looking for sc3 in this instance.

Comment: Please explain why. `sc2` is the actual class of the instance, as an instance of `sc2` is created: `sc2().get_...`. `sc3` is there just for avoiding the ambiguity of "most derived class".

Comment: Many thanks. Your proposal worked just fine, but the proposal using classmethod from @poorsod did not when I would have expected both to yield the same result.

Comment: @Jonathan The answer using classmethods works, too. According to your edit you are just using it the wrong way. See my comment below your question above.

Comment: @tobias_k in this approach you need to create an instance first, is there any way to get the sub class name (exact requirement in the question), but without creating an instance??

Comment: @Anubis What do you mean? You have a `class c` and want to get it's name? Just do `c.__name__`? Or do you want the name of some subclass of `c`? If so, _which_ subclass to take (there could be many) without providing an instance of that subclass?

Comment: @tobias_k can you please check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24953216/1547699

Answer (score 9):

You need a [class method](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

```
class bc(Object):
    @classmethod
    def get_subclass_name(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    def somemethod(self):
        x = self.get_subclass_name()
```

Normal methods, when invoked, get passed the instance as the first parameter. This is why you see `self` everywhere in Python.

When you invoke a class method, however, the *concrete class of the instance* is passed to the function. We usually use the name `cls`, as I have done here.

The classic use case for class methods is *alternative constructors*. For example, the standard library's `dict` class provides a [`fromkeys`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) class method, which constructs a new dict from the supplied keys and a single value. You could construct such a dict manually, but the Python developers made life easy for you!

Comment: If sc is derived from bc, you will get bc as the name, not sc as I want. I have already tried this.

Comment: Why not just use `self.__class__`?

Comment: @Jonathan Have I misunderstood your requirements? If you call `get_subclass_name` on an instance of `sc`, it'll return `'sc'`.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, this is roughly equivalent to using `self.__class__`, but it's _much_ more Pythonic (it's both less verbose and more explicit).