# Getting derived class name statically in python

Tags: python

How can i implement the static method `get_class_name()` to get the expected results.

I need to get the correct class name without instantiating. (I know this can be done with an instance). Python version is 2.6.

```
class base_class():
    @staticmethod
    def get_class_name():
        return <??>

class sub_classA(base_class):
    pass

class sub_classB(base_class):
    pass

print sub_classA.get_class_name() # should print 'sub_classA'
print sub_classB.get_class_name() # should print 'sub_classB'
print base_class.get_class_name() # should print 'base_class'
```

Comment: i don't know how @user2357112 see this as a duplicate of the question of the given link. did you even read the question??

Comment: Voted to re-open as I disagree that this is a duplicate.

Comment: You will find that your question and the linked question have the exact same answer.

Comment: @user2357112 seriously?? can you please explain how that answer relate to this

Comment: Have you tried this: `@classmethod def get_class_name(cls): return cls.__name__`?

Comment: You are using the wrong function. You want `classmethod`, which provides the class as an argument to the method. The linked question has answers that thoroughly explain this.

Comment: well, in that case i'm obliged to provide the class as an argument. Is that the only way? because, if i can write the method as i've shown/imagined, i can forget about it forever. If i have to pass the class every time to get its name, then it's like i wont need a method anyway, instead of passing the class and getting the name, i can directly write the name there, that's what i thought. I thought this should be possible. please let me know if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Anubis You forgot that the class is passed implicitly when you call the class method just the way you did in your example. Just try it.

Comment: You don't need to pass `cls` to a class method any more than you need to pass `self` to an instance method. Just read the dupe. It explains everything.

Comment: Wow, thanks! that's exactly what i wanted. never knew that (i'm learning)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a`classmethod`instead:

```
class base_class():
    @classmethod
    def get_class_name(cls):
        return cls.__name__

class sub_classA(base_class):
    pass

class sub_classB(base_class):
    pass

print sub_classA.get_class_name() # -> sub_classA
print sub_classB.get_class_name() # -> sub_classB
print base_class.get_class_name() # -> base_class
```

Of course you don't need a function/method to do this and could just access the`__name__`class attribute directly:

```
print sub_classA.__name__ # -> sub_classA
# etc
```